# Mask part of the String data which is of different lengths using Java

Tags: java, string, mask

I am in need to mask PII data for my application. The PII data will be of String format and of variable lengths, as it may include name, address, mail id's etc.

So i need to mask these data before logging them, it should not be a full mask instead, if the length of string is less than or equal to 8 characters then mask the first half with "XXX etc.."

If the length is more than 8 then mask the first and last portion of the string such that only the mid 5 characters are visible.
I know we can do this using java sub-stringa nd iterating over the string, but want to know if there is any other simple solution to address this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Apache Commons, you can do like

```
String maskChar = "*";

//number of characters to be masked
String maskString = StringUtils.repeat( maskChar, 4);

//string to be masked
String str = "FirstName";

//this will mask first 4 characters of the string
System.out.println( StringUtils.overlay(str, maskString, 0, 4) );
```

You can check the string length before generating `maskString` using if else statement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function; change the logic of half's as per your needs:

```
public static String maskedVariableString(String original)
    {
        String maskedString = null;
        if(original.length()<9)
        {
            int half = original.length()/2;
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder("");
            for(int i=0;i<(original.length()-half);i++)
            {
                sb.append("X");
            }
            maskedString = original.replaceAll("\\b.*(\\d{"+half+"})", sb.toString()+"$1");

        }
        else
        {
            int maskLength = original.length()-5;
            int firstMaskLength = maskLength/2;
            int secondMaskLength = maskLength-firstMaskLength;

            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder("");
            for(int i=0;i<firstMaskLength;i++)
            {
                sb.append("X");
            }
            String firstMask = sb.toString();

            StringBuilder sb1 =new StringBuilder("");
            for(int i=0;i<secondMaskLength;i++)
            {
                sb1.append("X");
            }
            String secondMask = sb1.toString();

            maskedString = original.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{"+firstMaskLength+"})(\\d{5})(\\d{"+secondMaskLength+"})", firstMask+"$2"+secondMask);
        }
        return maskedString;
    }
```

Explanation:

- **()** groups the regular expression and we can use $ to access this group($1, $2,$3).
- The \b boundary helps check that we are the start of the digits (there are other ways to do this, but here this will do).
- (\d{+half+}) captures (half) no of  digits to Group 1.  The same happens in the else part also.

Comment: It would be better to provide some input and output samples.